# Psychological effect of jinn on human

Tags: jinn

Sometimes, during sleep at night, I scream and yell but I don't wake up, My parents tell me about this in the morning but I can't remember a single thing.
Last night I screamed so loud around 1:30 AM and woke up seeing my dad holding me and saying, what happened, but I can't remember anything. My mother is a very religious person, she said it's happening because of a jinn.
I am a 2nd-year college student, somewhat depressed about my academic career(that's normal ig). I am just curious about this, can a jinn cause me to scream during sleep? but not be woken up, don't remember anything, not be scared ??
[sorry for my bad English]

Comment: First, your English is not bad at all. Second, this is looking for personal advice, which is not bad as such, but you will get few to no answers here because, this place is to share knowledge of Islam in general, (regrettably) not for personal situations. Third, partly on your behave, I have asked this question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/81071/55518