# What is a jinn?

Tags: jinn

As far as I know, a Jinn is of a race that Allah has made out of (pure, smokeless) fire just like humans where made by Him out of clay.

Reading recent questions, and old ones "botted up" by the Community Bot, most of them looking like asking for personal advice, often asking about jinns.

I cannot help but feel that there is some misunderstanding of jinns in common folklore and what is really based on Islam.

From the questions, it looks like jinns are looked on as a kind of devils, bringing harm, bad luck and nightmares.

From my very, very bad translation of the Quran I once had I remember a Sura where Prophet Muhammad stated that when he was speaking, there was also a number of jinns present.

So they cannot be all that bad, not all of them.

Sorry if I can't make a clear and unambiguous question out of my thoughts. I will sharpen it if someone can direct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know about Jinn from what was revealed in Quran and Sunnah Only. There are lot of folklore and tales created around Jinn and people imagination go towards them when they hear about Jinn.

Yes, there are good Jinns as mentioned in Jinn Sura

> And among us are Muslims [in submission to Allah ], and among us are
> the unjust. And whoever has become Muslim - those have sought out the
> right course. [Quran 72:14](https://legacy.quran.com/72/14)

It is a hidden world which we don't know (the word jinn itself means hidden), we should not try to explore this as we can go astray if we try to do so.

> True, there were people among mankind who took shelter with people
> among the Jinns, but they increased them in folly. [Quran 72:6](https://quran.com/72/6)

> For to Allah belong the Forces of the heavens and the earth; and Allah
> is Exalted in Power, Full of Wisdom. [Quran 42:7](https://quran.com/48/7)

Comment: Up one for providing a link to the Sura that I have lost. I miss (and in such my question was not clear, and gets more clearer now in the progress), what is the folklore in detail and how has that thinking gone wrong?

Comment: We can see many tales in which people invoke jinn and they come and help them or grant wishes. But it is wrong to invoke jinn if they are not responding to you. "And who could be more astray than those who call upon others besides Allah—˹others˺ that cannot respond to them until the Day of Judgment, and are ˹even˺ unaware of their calls?"  Quran 46:5

Comment: I get your meaning, and I am quite with you, but "But it is wrong to invoke jinn if they are not responding to you. " Makes me think of something form Shakespeare, someone boasted: "I can call the spirits from the deepest depths" ... and then be simply replied "but will they come?"

Comment: @Gyro It's not so much that the thinking has gone _wrong_, rather so much of what we (think we) know about the Jinn comes from non-Islamic sources that we have no way to confirm how reliable it is vs how much of it is just superstition.

Comment: @goldPseudo My question is not so much about reliability. The Quran, as much as it holds, is clear about it (but cannot mention everything about it). I'm asking about those pre-islamic believes that resound in many questions.  Without that known, how could these questions be answered? I have a background of maths, and I sure know that an error can only be truly corrected by understanding the source.

Comment: @goldPseudo In other words: to best cure an illness, you have to understand the disease. Otherwise you are left with cutting and burning.